# java/tomcat web hosting

Tags: java, bandwidth, web-hosting

Sorry about repeating the Question, but this is some what different.

I'm looking for some web hosting around 15$/month with unlimited bandwidth and space or what ever be a good deal.

Site is using struts2 java framework mysql database.

I have already seen plan of MochaHost.com UnlimitedGb.com although their plan look full of feature and even in my price range but lately i see a lot of negative reviews on 
www.web-hosting-top.com so that makes me further confused and i'm not able to make up my mind which to use.

Can you guys suggest any good trusted java hoster. and also if somebody can point how much bandwidth and disk space is requred for any avg data driven site.

[some thing about the site so that you can figure out the data bandwidth: site generally will have 2 types of login general user and org user. general user can login and submit their feedback which will be of 9 text fields on avg 100 char each one file upload document type avg size 100KB other Org user can have the report feature based on the feedback site is new so not much user/view but expecting some what 100K users in first 4 months, No audio/video/flash is used on site just plan text/css/image to make it attractive ]
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rain, the truth is that you won't find a **good** hosting plan for that money. You might use the ones you mentioned, but prepare to wait a few seconds for each request.
That's because all shared hosting plans use one cpu unit to host lots of applications.

If you need a tiny bit of performance, you'll  need to jump to a Virtual Private Server (VPS). The good ones are around $50 and ensure 256m of memory (as you might know that's almost nothing for a java app).
There are some cheap VPS ($20/month) like http://vpslink.com/, but I don't know how good they are.

Comment: Yes you are correct I'm considering eatj xen vps plan. its in my limit and it gives vps as well don't know much about the service quality but any way one have to proceed isn't it :) hope to have a good service.Thanks for reply